# Getting cucumberException in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestContext while running cucumber task

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am new to cucumber-jvm. While running cucumber task I am getting this error.

`:cucumberException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/testng/ITestContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:91)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:69)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.ITestContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 11 more`

I am unable to find why I am getting this error. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

 task cucumber() {
     dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
      doLast {
          javaexec {
              main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
              classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime +   sourceSets.main.output     + sourceSets.test.output
              args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'com', 'src/test/resources']
         }
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4'
    compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.1'
}
```

Comment: The looks real strange. I would try two things: 

1. Try to figure out if there is a testng dependency around: `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency testng`

2. Try to added a testng dependency:
`compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-testng:1.2.4'`?

Comment: I got this after running your command: 
   ` $ ./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency testng
    :dependencyInsight
    No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration   ':compile'`

But after adding testng dependency, it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TobiSH Though I am not sure, why it needs testng dependency.

Comment: Me neither. Do you have some github repo to have a closer look?

Comment: @TobiSH Please check the code base. I have created a repository and pushed the code [github link](https://github.com/asisdatta/test-gradle-cucumber).

Comment: I sent you a pull request. Basicly I just restructured the source-code a little (moved them to different folder) so that the cucumber framework is able to match the feature file with your test-code. By that you dont need an own gradle task to run the cucumber tests. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is not to call the cucumber cli manualy. This will be handled by the testing framework of your choice (junit in your case). So get rid of the special task for cucumber. This shall be handled by the default gradle test task. Please see the inital setup here: https://github.com/tobi-sh/test-gradle-cucumber.

If you really want to seperate the bdd tests from your other unit test than create an own configuration for the bdd test and include them into your testing folders on demand.